# Not able to success to create multiple json object in a array at dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays

PartTextValue array values are not iterate in this below json object. I want add another json based on index and OUPUT will be come like as below

```
{text:'I want to eat'},
  {
    text: ' Fruits',
    entityType: '@Banana',
    alias: 'Fruits',
    userDefined: true
  },
{text:''},
  {
    text: ' Fruits',
    entityType: '@mango',
    alias: 'Fruits',
    userDefined: true
  },
{text:''},
  {
    text: ' Zoom',
    entityType: '@Zoom',
    alias: 'Zoom',
    userDefined: true
  }
]
```

```
let part;
let PartTextValue=[ 'I want to eat', '', '', '' ];
let entriesValue =["Fruits","Fruits","Zoom"];
let entityName=["Banana", "mango", "Zoom"];
part = entriesValue.map((val, index) => {
    return { text: PartTextValue[index] }, {
        text: " " + val,
        entityType: '@' + entityName[index],
        alias: val,
        userDefined: true
    };
});
console.log(part)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and wrap the return value in an array. Everything else is perfect.

> You're getting the second result only. If you return two value from a
> function separated with comma then the second one will get returned.

```js
function getValue() {
  return 1, 2;
}

console.log(getValue());
```

```js
const arr = [
  { text: "I want to eat" },
  {
    text: " Fruits",
    entityType: "@Banana",
    alias: "Fruits",
    userDefined: true,
  },
  { text: "" },
  {
    text: " Fruits",
    entityType: "@mango",
    alias: "Fruits",
    userDefined: true,
  },
  { text: "" },
  {
    text: " Zoom",
    entityType: "@Zoom",
    alias: "Zoom",
    userDefined: true,
  },
];

const PartTextValue = ["I want to eat", "", "", ""];
const entriesValue = ["Fruits", "Fruits", "Zoom"];
const entityName = ["Banana", "mango", "Zoom"];
const part = entriesValue.flatMap((val, index) => {
  return [
    { text: PartTextValue[index] },
    {
      text: " " + val,
      entityType: "@" + entityName[index],
      alias: val,
      userDefined: true,
    },
  ];
});
console.log(part);
```